# Parse CSV string into Array of Integers

Tags: c#, arrays, parsing, csv, int

I have a text box field inputs 123,145,125  I to separate this field into an array of integers. And validate this field true or false if everything is parsed right.

CODE:

```
private bool chkID(out int[] val) 
{
    char[] delimiters = new char[] { ',' };
    string[] strSplit = iconeID.Text.Split(delimiters);  


    int[] intArr = null;
    foreach (string s in strSplit) //splits the new parsed characters 
    {
        int tmp;
        tmp = 0;
        if (Int32.TryParse(s, out tmp))
        {
            if (intArr == null)
            {
                intArr = new int[1];
            }
            else
            {
                Array.Resize(ref intArr, intArr.Length + 1);
            }
            intArr[intArr.Length - 1] = tmp;
        }

        if (Int32.TryParse(iconeID.Text, out tmp))
        {
            iconeID.BorderColor = Color.Empty;
            iconeID.BorderWidth = Unit.Empty;

            tmp = int.Parse(iconeID.Text);
            val = new int[1];
            val[0] = tmp;
            return true;
        }


    }
    val = null;
    ID.BorderColor = Color.Red;
    ID.BorderWidth = 2;
    return false;
}
```

//new Code:
private bool chkID(out int[] val) //bool satus for checkID function
        {
            string[] split = srtID.Text.Split(new char[1] {','});
            List numbers = new List();
            int parsed;

```
        bool isOk = true;
        foreach( string n in split){
            if(Int32.TryParse( n , out parsed))
                numbers.Add(parsed);
            else
                isOk = false;
        }
        if (isOk){
            strID.BorderColor=Color.Empty;
            strID.BorderWidth=Unit.Empty;
            return true;
        } else{
            strID.BorderColor=Color.Red;
            strID.BorderWidth=2;
            return false;
        }
            return numbers.ToArray();
        }
```

Comment: A good idea would be to tell us what problem you are having with your current code.

Comment: And what language it is.  I'm guessing C#, but that's because I know it's not Java.

Comment: The problem I'm having is I need to download XML data for given ID's in a text field.

For an example: "123,456,789"

Parse this CSV string into an array of integers, validate the fields, and download XML Data for the valid ID's

thanks

Chad

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The given function seems to do too much.  Here's one that answers the question implied by your title:

```
//int[] x = SplitStringIntoInts("1,2,3, 4, 5");

static int[] SplitStringIntoInts(string list)
{
    string[] split = list.Split(new char[1] { ',' });
    List<int> numbers = new List<int>();
    int parsed;

    foreach (string n in split)
    {
        if (int.TryParse(n, out parsed))
            numbers.Add(parsed);
    }

    return numbers.ToArray();
}
```

**EDIT (based on your comment on the question)**

You've defined the three things this function needs to do.  Now you just need to create methods for each.  Below are my guesses for how you could implement them.

```
int[] ValidateIDs(int[] allIDs)
{
    List<int> validIDs = new List<int>(allIDs);

    //remove invalid IDs

    return validIDs.ToArray();
}

void DownloadXmlData(int[] ids)
{
    ...
}
```

Now you just execute your new functions:

```
void CheckIconeID(string ids)
{
    int[] allIDs = SplitStringIntoInts(ids);
    int[] validIDs = ValidateIDs(allIDs);

    DownloadXmlData(validIDs);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I really wanted to comment on @Austin Salonen's answer, but it didn't fit.  It is a great answer for the question asked, but i wanted to expand the discussion a bit more generally on csv/int conversion part.

- It's  small point, not worth much debate but I would consider swapping the `foreach` loop for a plain `for` loop.   You'll likely end up with simpler IL (read faster). See (http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/foreach.aspx, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973839.aspx [Use For Loops for String Iteration—version 1]).
- I would create two methods -- one that is safe and uses `TryParse` and only adds the "good" values, another that is not as safe, but faster.

Proposed "safe" function (with overload in case you don't want to know the bad values)...

```
    public static int[] SplitAsIntSafe (this string csvString) {
        List<string> badVals;
        return SplitAsIntSafe(csvString, ',', out badVals);
    }
    public static int[] SplitAsIntSafe (this string delimitedString, char splitChar, out List<string> badVals) {
        int         parsed;
        string[]    split   = delimitedString.Split(new char[1] { ',' });
        List<int>   numbers = new List<int>();
        badVals             = new List<string>();

        for (var i = 0; i < split.Length; i++) {
            if (int.TryParse(split[i], out parsed)) {
                numbers.Add(parsed);
            } else {
                badVals.Add(split[i]);
            }
        }
        return numbers.ToArray();
    }
```

Proposed "fast" function ....

```
    public static int[] SplitAsIntFast (this string delimitedString, char splitChar) {
        string[]    strArray = delimitedString.Split(splitChar);
        int[]       intArray = new int[strArray.Length];

        if(delimitedString == null) {
            return new int[0];
        }
        for (var i = 0; i < strArray.Length; i++) {
            intArray[i] = int.Parse(strArray[i]);
        }
        return intArray;
    }
```

Anyway, hope this helps someone.

Comment: Failure shouldn't be silent, thus I don't like your "safe" version.  Modelling it after `TryParse` itself, with results written out to a parameter, and return value indicating whether a parse error occurred, would my a much better choice in my opinion.  (The result parameter could either be an `out string[]`, but I'd suggest having the caller provide a `List<string>` to which the parseable columns elements are added.  Alternatively, return an `int?[]`, which retains information about *which* columns failed to parse.

Comment: @Ben, I think you make too broad a statement.  It depends on what you want.  If you ALREADY KNOW you have mixed values and just want the ints the version I posted accomplishes that goal.  If you are trying to validate input and WANT TO KNOW if bad input is coming in then I agree with you. 

In the later case I don't think i would do a bool return value.  It provides me some information, but possibly not enough.  I would return the int[] of good entries and use an optional output param of `string[] Bad` so you can show your users the bad values rather than leave him/her to search the string.

Answer (score 1):

It might be worth your while to check out this [FileHelper](http://www.filehelpers.com/) and also [CSV Reader](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/database/CsvReader.aspx)

Hope they will help you...
Take care,
Tom

Comment: But the question is asking how to parse a CSV string from a form field, not a CSV *file*.

Comment: Ok, Make a text stream from the string input, accordingly to the FileHelpers util, there is a method ReadString which is part of the CommonEngine Class...see the prototype below...

public static object[] ReadString(
   Type recordClass,
   string input
);

Comment: Actually, disregard the first few words up to accordingly..I'll repeat again, my bad! accordingly to the FileHelpers util, there is a method ReadString which is part of the CommonEngine Class...see the prototype below... public static object[] ReadString( Type recordClass, string input );

Answer (score 1):

There is a good free library for parsing CSV files: [FileHelpers](http://www.filehelpers.com)

```
    using FileHelpers;

    // First declare the record class

    [Delimitedrecord(";")]
    public class SampleType
    {
        public string Field1;
        public int    Field2;
    }


    public void ReadExample()
    {
        FileHelperEngine engine = new FileHelperEngine(typeof(SampleType));

        SampleType[] records;    

        records = (SampleType[]) engine.ReadFile("source.txt");

        // Now "records" array contains all the records in the
        // sourcefile and can be acceded like this:

        int sum = records[0].Field2 + records[1].Field2;
    }
```

Comment: But the question is asking how to parse a CSV string from a form field, not a CSV *file*.

Answer (score 0):

```
public bool ParseAndCheck(string source,
    out IList<int> goodItems, out IList<string> badItems)
{
    goodItems = new List<int>();
    badItems = new List<string>();

    foreach (string item in source.Split(','))
    {
        int temp;
        if (int.TryParse(item, out temp))
            goodItems.Add(temp);
        else
            badItems.Add(item);
    }

    return (badItems.Count < 1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In .NET 2.0 you could write

```
string test = "123,14.5,125,151,1.55,477,777,888";

bool isParsingOk = true;


int[] results = Array.ConvertAll<string,int>(test.Split(','), 
    new Converter<string,int>(
        delegate(string num)
        {
            int r;
            isParsingOk &= int.TryParse(num, out r);
            return r;
        }));
```

Answer (score -1):

This is simple and I think works pretty well. It only return valid numbers:

```
static int[] SplitStringIntoInts(string list)
{            
    int dummy;            
    return (from x in list.Split(',')
            where int.TryParse(x.ToString(), out dummy)
            select int.Parse(x.ToString())).ToArray();           
}
```

Comment: Sorry, this won't work.  "from x in list" means that each iteration will involve a single char in the string 'list'.  So if I run test case "10,20" I will get int[]{1,0,2,0} - not the desired result.

Comment: @Kirk: That's easily remedied by changing it to `from x in list.Split(',')`.

Comment: @David: But why call `ToList` followed by `ToArray`? Just `ToArray` on its own will do the job.

Comment: I reworked it a little bit (Split(',')). It's tinier than the other solutions. Why the downvote? :(

Comment: I don't like the call to `TryParse` immediately followed by a repeated call to `Parse`. I understand that you did that to compress code, but I don't think it's a good idea in general. Either use a statement lambda with a single `TryParse` that properly captures parse result, or just use `Parse` and catch exception (if list is large, and is generally not expected to hold incorrect values, the perf hit is negligible, but the code will be more concise).

Comment: @Pavel fair enough. I won't refute the opinion of a 17.5k guy :)

Comment: So what about "private bool checkID(out int[] val)"...how do you make it true if "123,456,789" is correct or false if "123,456,abc," false.

The only thing I would like for this function to do is return true of flase. 

thank you 

Chad